# How to configure router and devices for subnetting?

Tags: subnet

I am new to Subnetting a network so please bear with me. I understood all theory but not able to find any information or tutorials that can explain practical steps and configuration require to achieve this. I want to divide my home network into two sub-nets. The gateway address is 192.168.1.1 and mask is 255.255.255.0. To divide it into two sub-network I understand that the mask need to be 255.255.255.128. But I can't get any help on internet about how to configure the routers for this? Do I need 3 routers for 2 sub-nets? If yes, what would be the network address and Mask on each router. I am happy to be corrected on my above understanding and would appreciate any help or link to resource. Please note that I have access to 3 router in total.

Update: More information:

This is something I want my network:

[image: network 1]

Comment: What router do you have? Most enterprise routers are able to subnet.

Comment: I have a D-link ADSL2 router. It is a basic home router. Sorry, I am not sure if I need a enterprise router to be able to subnet my home network.

Comment: can you please post the exact model?

Comment: What kind of connection and separation do you want between your subnets?

Comment: It is TP-LINK TD-VG3631 router

Comment: @RalfFriedl I am doing experiment with subnetting at home. I want to create a logical partition where access can be controlled and restricted from other subnets. i.e. Guest Wifi. Also I want to separate the bandwidth hungry devices on different subnet.

Comment: for the netmask 255.255.255.128 the first subnet is `net ID: 192.168.1.0`, `hosts: 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.126`, `broadcast: 192.168.1.127`; second subnet is `net ID: 192.168.1.128`, `hosts: 192.168.1.129 - 192.168.1.254`, `broadcast: 192.168.1.255'.

Comment: *I want to divide my home network into two sub-nets.* It is a way which you select to achieve some goal. The goal itself is unknown for us yet. It is bad... because it is possible that you select wrong way to solve your primary task.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain how your network looks like. The usual rule is **one subnet per LAN segment**. If you just have one LAN segment, two subnets are a bad idea. If you want "virtual" subnets on a single LAN segment, have a look at VLAN tagging. In any way, please describe your **main goal**: Why do you think you need two subnets?

Comment: You can't separate **securely** devices behind such router you have. The simplest solution for you is to get 2 more routers/NAT/firewall and connect their WAN ports to LAN  of TP-LINK TD-VG3631. This way devices behind those two routers will be separated from each other while having connection to internet

Comment: @Alex I am able to do this but that is not subnetting? Please correct me if I am wrong. Regards

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for response. I have included more information in the question.

Comment: @ akajain No, my solution isn't subnetting, but stronger, it is physical separation. In case of subnetting, anyone (real people or malware) has ability to change network settings and jump between subnets as needed, while in my solution it isn't possible, both networks will stay behind Firewall/NAT,

Answer (score 3):

A router is a device that connects two or more networks. If you want two networks, there is no need for three routers, also no obvious benefit.

If you want to experiment and learn, I recommend getting a cheap router that is supported by [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/). OpenWRT is a Linux system designed for routers. Most home routers already run a Linux system, but it is usually locked down by the vendor and less flexible.

You could also see whether you can run OpenWRT on your main router, but I don' recommend that, if you misconfigure your router, you won't be able to search the internet for help.

With an additional router, you can split your internal network in two, one part between the main router and the second router, the other part behind the second router. You can connect your second router to the main router and have two subnets behind the second router. You can setup iptables to allow or deny access between the networks as you like.

If you want just a guest Wifi, You can also get a simple router, use the manufacturer's NAT configuration, connect your devices to the new router and the router together with the guests to the main router. You can also reverse the configuration, but without additional blocking, devices in the second router have access to devices on the main router.

Regarding subnets, the only requirement is that they don't contain public addresses and that they are distinct.

You can have one subnet `192.168.1.0/25`, this includes the addresses from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.0.127`, although the lowest and the highest address are not used. Similarly you can have the other subnet `192.168.1.128/25`, this includes the addresses from `192.168.1.128` to `192.168.1.255`. But as you can use the whole private address space, you can also use `192.168.2.0/24` for your second subnet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't subnet a network, you subnet a network block. If you want to two devices to connect to each other without a router between them, they should be on the same network.

If you want to have two subnets, 192.168.1.0/25 and 192.168.1.128/25 then you don't want a physical network numbered 192.168.1.0/24 because that would include both blocks in the same physical network.

Instead, change router A's LAN side to something else. For example, you could configure router A's LAN side to 192.168.9.1/24. That creates a new network to connect the three routers and you could assign router B the address 192.168.9.2/24 on that network and router C can be 192.168.9.3/24 on that network. Now, router A is routing between the 192.168.9.0/24 network and the 192.168.1.0/25 network. The 192.168.9.0/24 network services to interconnect the routers.

For this to work, however, you would need all three routers to understand how to route to all the networks involved. For example, routers A and B would need a route to 192.168.1.128/128 through 192.168.9.3 so they know to forward traffic to hosts on that subnet to router C. You can do this with static routes or using a dynamic routing protocol like OSPF.

This will be a fairly complex network to manage and maintain, and giving Internet access to the 192.168.1.128/128 network and 192.168.1.0/128 networks will require configuring some device to NAT for them.

Answer (score 0):

But, the slower router C could be configured as an access point instead.

Plug the WAN port of router C to a LAN port of router B.
Router B will handle all DHCP requests.

- Enable QoS on Router B.
- For the Wireless settings on Router C. for both the 2.4 and 5GHz bands, assign the same SSID name and password.
- On router B, for both the 2.4 and 5GHz bands, assign the same SSID name and password, but different from the SSID name and password used on Router C.
- Have all your slower devices connect to the SSID for Router C, and all the bandwidth intensive devices connect to Router B.

On Router B, assign the IP/MAC of Router C a lower priority in the QoS panel and, boom, mission accomplished. All on the same subnet and the slower devices will be less demanding of your Internet bandwidth.